# Identifications for the linear and non-linear models

Tags: linear-model, nonlinear

Consider a linear model and a non-linear model:
$$Y=X'\beta+u$$
$$Y=m\left(X;\beta\right)+u$$

Then, in my understanding, the identification conditions for $\beta$ in the linear model are

Condition 1: For some $\beta_0$, $\mathbb{E}\left[Y\middle|X\right]=X'\beta_0$

Condition 2: $\mathbb{E}\left[XX'\right]$ has full rank

and, in the non-linear model, the identification requires

Condition 3: For some $\beta_0$, $\mathbb{E}\left[Y|X\right]=m\left(X;\beta_0\right)$

Condition 4: $\mathbb{E}\left[\left(Y-m\left(X;\beta_0\right)\right)^2\right]<\mathbb{E}\left[\left(Y-m\left(X;\beta\right)\right)^2\right]$ for all $\beta\neq \beta_0$

Here, because Condition 1 is a special case of Condition 3, I thought that Condition 2 may be also a special case of Condition 4, or at least there should be some link between them.

So, I first rewrote Condition 4 as below
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\left(Y-X'\beta_0\right)^2\right]<\mathbb{E}\left[\left(Y-X'\beta\right)^2\right]\quad \textrm{for all} \quad \beta \neq \beta_0$$

Then, both Conditions 2 and 4 seem to say something about the uniqueness of $\beta_0$.

But, I am not sure what is the exact link between Conditions 2 and 4.

Does Condition 2 is a special case of Condition 4? If that is not, not is the link between them?

Comment: Condition 2 is about identifiability. Condition 4 is just about using least squares  as an estimation criterion. They dont correspond

Comment: Thank you so much, now my question became more clear. Condition 2 is also related to the consistency of LSE, and that is the reason why I thought that Conditions 2 could be the counterpart of Condition 4 in the linear model. And, your answer is still No, right?

Comment: Condition 2 is not particularly an issue with least squares. If $X$ itself is not of full column rank, then substituting say an $L_1$ norm in place of an $L_2$ norm is no help; the model would still be unidentifiable. The ridge in parameter space (a ridge in negative loss as a function of parameters) would still be present -- so an infinite set of parameter values would all give the same fit.

Comment: Normally in regression (etc) you're conditioning on the x's, so - given they're being treated as fixed - I'm not sure we need expectations on functions of $X$ alone.